# How to extract sub matrix indices from a matrix?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have a `uint16` image of size 512*512. The problem is that the image is all black except there is a medium object of uniform intensity of value 40000. This object has a black hole and I need to extract the indexes of this hole.

So the matrix is in the form of all zeroes, and in some region of the matrix we have a submatrix filled with the value 40000, and in this submatrix we have another submatrix of zeroes. This zero submatrix is the required one to be extracted in terms of its indices. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *very* simple solution would be to use [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html). For example:

```
>> data = 40000.*[0 0 0 0 0; 0 1 1 1 0; 0 1 0 1 0; 0 1 1 1 0; 0 0 0 0 0]

data =

           0           0           0           0           0
           0       40000       40000       40000           0
           0       40000           0       40000           0
           0       40000       40000       40000           0
           0           0           0           0           0

>> labelMatrix = bwlabel(~data)

labelMatrix =

     1     1     1     1     1
     1     0     0     0     1
     1     0     2     0     1
     1     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1

>> holeIndex = find(labelMatrix == 2)

holeIndex =

    13
```

The success of this is based on many assumptions, such as there only being one bright object and one hole in it. A more robust solution would require an example of the images you're analyzing, and might involve some preprocessing of the image and the use of functions such as [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to identify areas of the image.